# Whats the correct method to chain Observable<void> with typescript (Angular)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I've been searching for the right/best/correct way to chain a few Observable methods. I've read on the using pipe() and map() and so on, but i'm not 100% i fully understand. The basis is i have a few actions to carry out, which some needs to be in sequence, and some dont.
Below are the 4 methods i need to call.

```
createOrder(order:Order):Observable<void>{
        return new Observable((obs)=>
                //Do Something
                obs.complete();
        )
}

updateCurrentStock(order:Order):Observable<void>{
        return new Observable((obs)=>
                //Do Something
                obs.complete();
        )
}

updateSalesSummary(order:Order):Observable<void>{
        return new Observable((obs)=>
                //Do Something
                obs.complete();
        )
}
updateAnotherDocument(order:Order):Observable<void>{
        return new Observable((obs)=>
                //Do Something
                obs.complete();
        )
}
```

From this 4, the flow should be `createOrder` ->`updateCurrentStock`->`updateSalesSummary, updateAnotherDocument`.
As of now, what i have is

```
var tasks = pipe(
    flatMap(e => this.createOrder(order)),
    flatMap(e => this.updateCurrentStock(order)),
    flatMap(e => forkJoin([this.updateSalesSummary(order),this.updateAnotherDocument(order)])),
  );
  of(undefined).pipe(tasks).subscribe({
    error: (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      obs.error(err);
    },
    complete: () => {
      console.log('completed');
      obs.complete();
    }
  });
```

It works, but i'm not sure if this is the right/cleanest way of doing it and if there is any possible issues in the future.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using `concat`

concat will subscribe to your streams in order (not starting the next until the previous one completes.

This should be roughly equivalent.

One difference here is that unlike `mergeMap`, you're not transforming the output of an api call, it still gets emitted. Since you're not doing anything with the `next` callback in your subscription, it'll still look similar in the case.

```js
concat(
  this.createOrder(order),
  this.updateCurrentStock(order),
  forkJoin([
    this.updateSalesSummary(order),
    this.updateAnotherDocument(order)
  ])
).subscribe({
  error: concosle.log,
  complete: () => console.log('completed');
});
```

---

#### An Aside:

Here's how I would re-write your original code to be a bit easier to read.

```js
this.createOrder(order).pipe(
  mergeMap(_ => this.updateCurrentStock(order)),
  mergeMap(_ => forkJoin([
    this.updateSalesSummary(order),
    this.updateAnotherDocument(order)
  ]),
).subscribe({
  error: (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    obs.error(err); // <-- What's obs here?
  },
  complete: () => {
    console.log('completed');
    obs.complete();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of rxjs operators, I recommend you read https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs.

When you have an observable that depends on other's value use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)

Example:

```js
const userId$: Observable<number>;

function getUserData$(userId: number): Observable<Data> {
  // yourService.fetchUser(userId);
}

userId$.pipe(switchMap((userId: number) => getUserData$(userId)));
```

When you do not care about the order, you can use:

- if you want to emit the last value when all observables complete: [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)
- if you want to emit every value as any observable emits a value: [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest)

Example:

```js
const userId$: Observable<number>;

function getUserAge$(userId: number): Observable<number> {
  // ...
}
function getUserName$(userId: number): Observable<String> {
  // ...
}
userId$.pipe(
  switchMap((userId: number) =>
    forkJoin([getUserAge$(userId), getUserName$(userId)])
  )
);
```

In your case I think the order does not matter, as none of your observables needs data from the previous one. So I think you should use `combineLatest`.
If the order of emission and subscription of inner observables is important, try [`concatMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap).